# Can TBytes, TByteDynArray, Array of Bytes be safely typecasted to each other?

Tags: delphi, casting

Since `TBytes`, `TByteDynArray`, and `array of Bytes` are all dynamic arrays of bytes, can typed variables be safely typecasted to each other?  (If I have a variable of `TBytes` can I simply typecast to `TByteDynArray` when using a method that defines parameters as `TByteDynArray` and vice-versa?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such typecasts are perfectly safe in all the Delphi implementations that I have ever encountered.

However, reinterpretation typecasts like this remove type checking, there is always a risk that future changes to the source code can result in hard to trace errors. I would always try to avoid casting if possible. For example, the very simplest thing you can do is to avoid using `array of Byte` as a type in your code and switch to `TBytes`.

If you must cast then wrap it up in a function to mitigate the risks I describe above.

```
function Bytes(const B: TByteDynArray): TBytes;
begin
  Result := TBytes(B);
end;
```

Comment: Adding an `inline` after the function declaration will make the code even more "transparent" in respect to the generated asm.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, that would make sense. Essentially this function does nothing but defeat the type system and so its perfect for inline!